# Device Logs not printing for android emulator using Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-emulator, adb

i have the following simple code in my Xamarin android c# app:

```
 [Activity(Label = "getSetTest", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Log.Info("UniqueTest", "hello");

        }


    }
```

However, the log is not showing in the device log output console. It is however showing in the regular Debug output in visual studio. No logs at all are appearing in the Device Log.I am testing it on an android emulator in visual studio.

Thanks

Comment: What about restart it? Or you can use `adb` command to get the device log.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Diagnostics.Debug is usually used to show the debug log in output window the thing that you seem to be looking for is the logcat.

> One very common trick developers use to debug their applications is to make calls to Console.WriteLine. However, on a mobile platform like Android there is no console. Android devices provides a log that you can use while writing apps. This is sometimes referred to as 'logcat' due to the command that you type to retrieve it.

Xamarin has a small guide on how to use the logcat which you will find [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/android-debug-log/)

Kindly revert in case this is not it.

Goodluck!

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply however I have already added the logcat and this is the issue - nothing is being logged to it.

Comment: From what i know log debug files are not supposed to go to the log cat that is why i sent you the link for it in the first place because there it shows how you can send it to the logcat

Comment: Well it only seems to work when I start the emulator first, and then add the android device log afterwards from Tools>Android>Device log. However, after that point when the emulator is already running, for subsequent testing the logs are not showing

Comment: or may be its too fast for your eye to catch on to have you throughly checked it out ?

Comment: now it is spammed with "audio flinger -1" errors, but when I type in a filter tag for the logs ive made they don't show..

Comment: can you upload one of your logs somewhere and tell me what are you looking for in it